# Validate a action in form when click commandbutton

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to know if is possible to validate dates before to execute the action to open a new tab in the navigator.

I have a form that have two fields to enter the date values, so when user press the `commandButton` it will open the other form with the values filtered in other tab.

So the problem is, if didn´t enter a correct `date` it will open the new tab.

```
<p:column>
  <p:calendar locale="pt_BR" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" value="#{relatorioDesempenhoAnalistaListBean.filter.dataInicial}" required="true" label="#{lbl['LABEL.RELATORIOANALISTA.ENTREDATAS']}"/>
</p:column>

<p:column>
  <p:calendar locale="pt_BR" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" value="#{relatorioDesempenhoAnalistaListBean.filter.dataFinal}" required="true"  label="#{lbl['LABEL.RELATORIOANALISTA.ENTREDATAS']}"/>
</p:column>


<p:column colspan="3" styleClass="columnRight">
  <p:commandButton value="#{lbl['BOTAO.GERARRELATORIO']}" action="form" ajax="false" onclick="target='_blank'"/>
</p:column>
```

My code is above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a custom date validator similar to this

```
@FacesValidator(value="check_If_date_is_valid")
public class CheckDate implements Validator{

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext facescontext, UIComponent uicomponent,Object obj) throws ValidatorException {
         Date _userInput=(Date)obj;
            if(isThisDateValid(_userInput.toString(),"dd/MM/yyyy")){
               //do nothing 
            }else{
                  throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("Date not valid"));
            }
     }

    public boolean isThisDateValid(String dateToValidate, String dateFromat){

    if(dateToValidate == null){
        return false;
    }

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFromat);
    sdf.setLenient(false);

    try {

        //if not valid, it will throw ParseException
        Date date = sdf.parse(dateToValidate);
        System.out.println(date);

    } catch (ParseException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

            

}
```

And on the page

```
<p:commandButton>
  <f:validator validatorId="check_If_date_is_valid" />
  <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

And add `<p:message/>`on the page to display the error message

If their is a validation error your action method of managedBean will not be called. and heance tab will not open.

Comment: I´m going to implement this code, but I have one doubt, it will stop to open the new tab?

Because my problem isn´t only the validation, but when I click in the button, it will call a new tab with the form with the registers, but if the dates are wrong it will open in the new tab the same page.

Comment: @BholaVishwakarma....you don't need to to explicitly implement `Ajax` tag for `<p:commandButton`> cause it's already implemented with `inbuilt` ajax

Comment: @BholaVishwakarma I don´t think that you understood or maybe I, but how can go to `page A` to `page B` with this code?

Yesterday I got problens that i can´t test your code

Comment: well the code is to test your valid date and if the date is valid what ever actionlistener you have written in you commandButton which is responsible to redirect will be executed :)