# Can a validator call by button action?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am trying to do following thing

```
<a4j:commandButton action="#{bean.addFeatures()}"  >
    <f:validator validatorId="defaultValueValidator" />
</a4j:commandButton>
```

But getting

> Parent not an instance of EditableValueHolder:
>   javax.faces.component.html.HtmlCommandButton@6e2388a1

What ever i am doing is right a Validator can be call from button action click?

I checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568182/validate-a-action-in-form-when-click-commandbutton)  Where So user did same .What other way to call a validator?

Version - JSF2.1.13

Comment: @BalusC I dont want to restrict I want to call validator on form submission ,right now i have added validator with some Textbox but this validator will be use when Textbox will be fill otherwise it will not called,But validator use for validate more than one component value so i want validator should always called when component have the values.

Comment: Whoever vote for close Please specify the reason as well it will gr8 help

Comment: @Kukeltje I Simply asked whatever i tried is possible or not ,if not possible then link i added have solution

Comment: The error states that it is NOT possible to add a validator to an a4j:commandButton... So Asking if it is possible or not is of no use. What you state in the comment is your real question... The link is about a `p:commandButton`, not a `a4j:commandButton`, that might be a reason for the other link saying it 'works'(weird, but ok)... And different jsf versions might be a reason... but I'd still look at the original problem

Comment: @Kukeltje Sounds Better It Mean PF added this feature in their component

Comment: No, since PF commandButton is also NOT an instance of 'EditableValueHolder', so I suspect it it cause by a difference in JSF implementation and version (or the 'accepted' answer in the other post did not work either)

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks for Info its possible to call this validator on form submission rather than adding with component?

Comment: **focus on the original problem** case closed for me

Comment: Hint: start using the OmniFaces utility framework:  http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateBean, http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/validator